# How to backup a Samsung mobile to linux?

Tags: linux, backup, android

I have only linux machines and I'd like to make a backup of my mobile.
How to do it, if a simple 'adb backup' doesn't work? On the android the Developer Options and USB Debugging are enabled.
The adb backup -shared starts, download about 1-1.5GB from the mobile's sd card which contains about 10-15GB, and stops working. There is no error message, but the backup file is corrupt.
If I try to use adb backup with other options, then the backup length is 0 or 41 bytes.
How can I backup my device? (Samsung's SmartSwitch doesn't work with wine :( )

Answer (score 1):

Try using `dd` (need root access). First, look in the `/dev/block/` (maybe `/dev/block/platform`) for a subdirectory called `by-name`. `cd` into the directory and type `ls -l`.
This will give you a list of the partitions names and locations. Once you have the location of the partition you want to back up, insert an SD card and type `dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p23 of="/storage/ext-sd-card-path/userdata.dd"` (or whatever applicable at `if`.

If you ever want to restore it, switch the `of` and `if`. (OF=Output File, IF=Input File):
`dd if="/storage/extsd/userdata.dd" if="/dev/block/mmcblk0p23"`
NOTE: Double check you have the correct partition number in the `mmcblk` path otherwise you may override another partition and brick your device!

Another alternative is to install a custom recovery. However, for both the above and just stated methods require root, and I am unaware of any non-root backup programs that work.

Also, I am not POSITIVE, but I think you need root access to use `adb backup` (as it uses the Android's internal `bu` command).